# Is the sentence "I now feel better" correct?

Tags: adverbs, syntax

Is the sentence "I now feel better" correct? Shouldn't it be "Now I feel better"? Or are both of them correct?

Comment: Both the sentences are correct,  but it's far more common to say "I  feel better now".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are correct.

'now' is an adverb, and adverbs, as a general rule, can be placed anywhere in the sentence as long as they don't interrupt [constituents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)). This, however, doesn't mean that all the possible placements would be common.

So all of these are acceptable:

> **Now** I feel better.
>   I **now** feel better.
>   I feel better **now**.

However, this is non-standard at best:

> %I feel **now** better.